# SEO - Where to go from here (how to build links etc)?

Tags: seo, links

I've been asked to find out about SEO and getting links. We are apparently in a contract with a firm who have made changes to our site code, changes to the text on the site, and registered us with a list of directories.  I've had no involvement with this until now.

They've told us to get links, and to add articles to our site.

I believe my boss expected all this to be included and it wasn't so now it's on me to know enough to do this and not wreck our ranking.

I've googled and think I know what to do with articles, which is simplistically just adding diverse content with each article focussing on a keyword, and create lots of them, right?  Some sites talk about percentage of keywords, does this really matter?

How do I get links though?  If I start mailing sites asking for a link isn't that just going to be considered spam?  Do we buy them?  If so, where?

As you can tell I'm completely new at this.  So many sites contradict each other, or promise impossible magic if you buy a product.  Is there a reasonable unbiased guide out there?  I have some tech IT background but am only a user as far as the web goes.

Sorry for the very basic questions.  Thanks.

**Update**

I was concentrating on the wrong question - I'd have been better knowing how best to proceed from here, hence the daft questions on how to build links etc.  Is there anything I need to watch out for when starting out with link building or writing articles?  ie damage our ranking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tell us is part of SEO (directory, article, linking, keyword research) but it's not a standard as "who do which part", I've seen SEO company do everything even the article creation about your company as I've seen company simply auditing your website and telling you what you should change.

It's often a question of funding, as you can see on this article by Rand Fishkin @ [SEOMoz](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/in-seo-do-you-get-what-you-pay-for), SEO charge from 50$ to 1000$ per hour. What you are saying now is that you must do a big part of the SEO, depending of the price you paid you would maybe need a talk with that firm.

Comment: Agreed. What's "usual" is irrelevant. You have a contract. What does it say? If it's vague enough to have resulted in this disagreement, then you/your employer and the firm need to get together and make it *not* vague.

Comment: Ok, that's a fair point of course - I wasn't involved in buying or negotiating which complicates it some - but we are where we are.  I haven't seen contract either, just what my boss told me, along with go figure out where we go from here!  Thanks for the link - it's enlightening.  The site looks like a good resource.

Comment: All I can say with thoses informations is that it looks like you are doing alot of the job an SEO firm should be doing for you...